# azure active directory with spring

Tags: spring, azure, spring-security, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I have try todo the demo that microsoft azure AD give for spring but that doesn't work 
thaht says always this error :
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval or this  one 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Not a URI because there is no client] is not a valid HTTP URL

you can see the code here :

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AADAuthenticationFilter aadAuthFilter;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(aadAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(oauth2ClientContext, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);

    }
}
```

classe controller :

```
@Controller
public class hellocontroler {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('Employees')")
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
```

class demo:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

poperty file:

```
# Specifies your Active Directory Application ID:
azure.activedirectory.clientId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# Specifies your secret key:
azure.activedirectory.clientSecret= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


# Specifies the list of Active Directory groups to use for authentication:
azure.activedirectory.activeDirectoryGroups=Employees
```